# MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top return 0.0

Tags: flutter, height, statusbar, flutter-layout

I am trying to get status bar height using below code but it always returns me 0.0:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top
```

I have tested it on real devices and emulator as well, the result is the same.

code:

```
    void _showBottomSheet(int selectedPosition) {
    showModalBottomSheetApp<void>(
        context: context,
        statusBarHeight: _navigationStore.statusBarHeight +
            MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
        dismissOnTap: true,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return _buildJobDetails(selectedPosition);
        });
  }
```

Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you post the full code where you are using that, because I tested it in iOS and Android, it is working just fine.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad i have updated the questions, please check and let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: There is no property like `statusBarHeight` in `showModalBottomSheet`

Comment: There's the same opened issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58150

Answer (score -1):

first, for showmodelbottomsheet it will always return as 0.0 because you set a context for this model sheet.

so declare statusBarHeight as seperate variable
Here is your solution,

```
var status_bar_height;

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    status_bar_height = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    return Scaffold();
}
```

use this status_bar_height for your modelsheet.